# Storing the output of a while loop in a variable

Tags: python

Hi :) I am making a quiz using python, i would like a user to answer 3 questions, and with each correct or incorrect answer, a user_score variable will get update.
What goes wrong is that when question 1 is answer and user moves to question 2, the user_score variable gets reset.

the while loop i use to process the user answers is below:

```
def check_submitted_answers(answer):
    perfect_answers = ['Mohammad','Abraham','Jesus']
    all_answers = ['Mohammad','Moses','Jesus','Solomon','Abraham']
    user_score = 0
    while True:
      if answer not in all_answers:
          print('Error: Please select one of the choices above')
          answer = input('Your answer is: ').capitalize()
      else:
              if answer in perfect_answers:
                print('Correct answer!!You got +1 point')
                user_score = user_score + 1
                perfect_answers.remove(answer)
                break
                
              else:
                print('Wrong answer.. You gained 0 points')
                user_score = user_score + 0
                break
                
    else:
      return answer
```

Whenever a new question comes in , the user_score variable is set to 0 again, i want the old value to be stored instead. thank you =)

Comment: In function you are setting it to 0. So at every call to the function `user_score` will be 0. If you want it as global variable then initialize it globally and then use it in the function.

Comment: Also, what are the questions? You seem to show a function which deals with the user answer to one of them. If this is the first answer, then, yes, surely the score should start off at `0`.

Answer (score 0):

yes, as GodWin pointed out, user_score lives only inside the function. Since you never return it, you will never access it from outside. I recommend sth like:

```
user_score = 0
def check_submitted_answers(answer):
    global user_score
    perfect_answers = ['Mohammad','Abraham','Jesus']
    all_answers = ['Mohammad','Moses','Jesus','Solomon','Abraham']
    while True:
        if answer not in all_answers:
            print('Error: Please select one of the choices above')
            answer = input('Your answer is: ').capitalize()
        else:
            if answer in perfect_answers:
                print('Correct answer!!You got +1 point')
                user_score = user_score + 1
                perfect_answers.remove(answer)
                break
                
            else:
                print('Wrong answer.. You gained 0 points')
                break
                
    else:
        return answer

check_submitted_answers("Jesus")
print(user_score) #prints 1
```

and I suspect you might wanna give some more details next time, because I am also a bit confused, like quamrana is. Hope this helped you tho ;). Let me know if this fixed your problem :D